# Running a Raspberry image with qemu-system-aarch64 having a systemd.run firstrun.sh script gets stuck

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, qemu

I'm trying to emulate a Raspberry Pi (+OS) with Qemu. I'd like the OS to execute a `firstrun.sh` script on boot to configure various things.

This is how I start qemu:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3b \
    -cpu cortex-a53 \
    -m 1G \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
    -drive "file=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk" \
    -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1 systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh systemd.run_success_action=none debug systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target" \
    -usb \
    -device usb-mouse \
    -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
    -nographic \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:22
```

However, when configuring Qemu/the Kernel to execute a systemd script `systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh`, it gets stuck and won't continue booting.

The last lines that get printed are:

```
[  OK  ] Finished Command from Kernel Command Line.
[  OK  ] Reached target Command from Kernel Command Line
```

This is a minimal firstrun script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
echo "This is the firstrun script"
rm -f /boot/firstrun.sh
sed -i 's| systemd.run.*||g' /boot/cmdline.txt
exit 0
```

To completely reproduce, these are the steps:

```
# Download image
wget https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2023-05-03/2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz
xz --extract 2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz

# Setup image - extract kernel.img and copy firstrun script
mount_dir=/mnt/raspberrypi
free_loopdev="$(sudo losetup -f)"
sudo kpartx -a -v 2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img
loop_mapper=/dev/mapper/$(basename "${free_loopdev}")
sudo mkdir -p "${mount_dir}"
sudo mount "${loop_mapper}p2" "${mount_dir}"
sudo mount "${loop_mapper}p1" "${mount_dir}/boot"
cp "${mount_dir}/boot/kernel8.img" .
cp "${mount_dir}/boot/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb" .
sudo cp firstrun.sh "${mount_dir}/boot"

# Run Qemu with Image
cmdline="rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1 systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh systemd.run_success_action=none debug systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target"
qemu-img resize -f raw "2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img" 4G
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3b \
    -cpu cortex-a53 \
    -m 1G \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
    -drive "file=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk" \
    -append "${cmdline}" \
    -usb \
    -device usb-mouse \
    -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
    -nographic \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:22
```

If I omit the `firstrun.sh` script, boot process works fine.

Why won't boot process continue when executing firstrun.sh?

Comment: Maybe the `/boot` filesystem is not mounted at that time?